# Mobile push notifications issues with listener (plugin MC-Cordova-Plugin)

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobilepush-ios, push-notification, push

- **Problem:**
  We are trying to implement Marketing cloud mobile push notifications with our hybrid ionic/cordova app, in which the listener does not trigger in both android and iOS.

  1. **Android:** With android we get the token with MCCordovaPlugin.getSystemToken(), and functions of isPushEnabled() / setContactKey() etc works fine. Then in salesforce-marketing cloud, we send a push to the user with that token, we receive the notification BUT through operating system, not via the listener that MC plugin provide us(setOnNotificationOpenedListener()). That means the push is sent properly, but the listener does not do anything.
  2. **iOS:**  With iOS we do not even get the token with MCCordovaPlugin.getSystemToken(). That means we cannot even send push notifications.

**Other info:**

- MCCordovaPlugin.sdkState() does not throw any info.
- We try this using only the MC plugin alone, BUT if we have firebase listeners, the notification does trigger there, that is a problem because we want to get rid of firebase push notifications, and as i said, we want to trigger a listener of the MC-plugin itself.
- Plugin: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin
- Version of the plugin installed: 7.5.0

Comment: Open a support ticket.